# Extracting to an Executeable JAR using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

This may be a simple question but how do i "build" my project so it becomes an executeable jar file if i use eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on Project -> Export -> Jar File / Runnable Jar File.

Comment: Is it executable  or plain jar file without any manifest file?

Comment: @Metalhead, You always have manifest. After compiling Java code to jar.

Comment: In both cases a manifest file will be created, but only when you choose Runnable Jar, it will also add main-class and classpath information from a given launch configuration into your manifest.

Comment: Perfect @ymene. Thanks for clarifying it as I doubted it earlier based on Vash comment.

Answer (score 1):

File -> Export -> Java -> Runnable Jar

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make an [**Ant**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) build script. This is a good solution because you can build the jar from both Eclipse and the command line.

Comment: Sorry...maybe not the simplest, but still my preferred solution.